# Display webpage address in browser address field which is loaded into iframe

Tags: asp.net, iframe

In my webapplication i have used iframe to display web page.how can i display page url which is loaded in iframe in web browser address field.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. What if http://fakebanksitewithrealbanksiteiniframe.com could just display http://yourbank.com?

Comment: actually we want to display url which is loading in actual.

Comment: Then in your HTML that includes the iframe, just add a `<span class="loading">Loading http://realsite.com below...</span>`.

Comment: which attributes class loading contains.?

Comment: is it possible or not to display page url into browser address bar..? page is load in iframe

Answer (score 0):

This is technically not possible. I would suggest you to put it at the back of the url instead like:

```
http(s)://mydomain/myurl?mysubUrl=...
```

But be aware that you have to escape the parameter!